# ag-Grid javascript cannot call a method in columnApi

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm trying to do a modification in 'ag-Grid' library and have a difficulty in calling a function inside the `columnApi`. The documentation says to use `gridOptions.columnApi.displayedCenterColumns()`.

Since I want to call the method inside the `columnApi` I used `this.columnApi.displayedCenterColumns()`. But could not find the `displayedCenterColumns()` method inside columnApi.

It's great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/), the method name should be '**get**DisplayedCenterColumns()':

```
gridOptions.columnApi.getDisplayedCenterColumns()
```